# Using (VB.NET) LINQ in UiPath to Group multiple columns

Tags: vb.net, linq, uipath

I am trying to GroupBy with LINQ. Simple enough, I can do that with one or more columns. The problem I am facing lies with grouping 5 columns that may contain the same data on different rows - if within the five columns, the data is same, they group to that data.

e.g I have the 6 columns and two rows of data. It should groupBy "Group Name" then by the 5 columns of Director Names

| Group Name | Director1Name | Director2Name | Director3Name | Director4Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Group A | Sam k | John D | Ben W | Reddy P |
| Group A | Matt R | Katt D | Sam k | Catty P |

The columns "Director1Name" and "Director3Name" have the same data "Sam K" as seen, what do I do to get that in the same group and the same names in column 2 (when grouped)

I have this half-done query in my assign activity, i realize I was checking through the same row:

```
(
    From row In dt_MasterListFiltered
    Let dn1 = row("Director1Name").ToString().Trim()
    Let dn2 = row("Director2Name").ToString().Trim()
    Let dn3 = row("Director3Name").ToString().Trim()
    Let dn4 = row("Director4Name").ToString().Trim()
    Let dn5 = row("Director5Name").ToString().Trim()
    Let Director = If(
        (
            (String.Equals(dn1, dn2)) Or 
            (String.Equals(dn1, dn3))
        ), dn1, dn2 )
    Group row By k = row("GroupName").ToString().Trim(), DirectorName = Director
    Into grp = Group
    Select dt_GroupedMasterlist.Rows.Add({k, DirectorName, String.Join(", ", grp.Select(Function(gr) String.Join("-", gr.ItemArray)))})
).CopyToDataTable
```

Note:

1. There are other columns and Data too, but this is the ones that need grouping
2. I understand that it would group the same because Group Name is same, but I am required to groupBy director name as well, which would ungroup them if I put it by Director1Name